# Insert script file using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a load of google sheet files that are used as a contract template for our business. I want have added some scripted functionality to the main template and ideally would like to import this into existing files that are already in use.

I already have a script set up that I can run to push new sheets into the existing documents if needed. I use:

```
var insertSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName(tabName);
var template = "";
insertSheet.copyTo(template).setName(tabName);
```

However, is there any way to perform a similar function but to insert script files into the documents?

For example, my new script file is entitled onEdit.gs ... can I push this somehow into an existing document?

Comment: You can use the Apps Script API.  [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/)  You'll need to use the REST API with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`  if you will be running the code from Apps Script.  I've only used it to overwrite code from one Apps Script file to another Apps Script file in my own account.  So I owned both files and they are in the same account.  If the target files are in someone else's Google account, they may need to enable the API in their account.  Maybe someone else knows the details.

Comment: If the information can be added to the comment of @Sandy Good, when you copy the script using Apps Script API, please do the following flow. 1. Create new project to Spreadsheet using projects.create method. 2. Copy the script using projects.updateContent method. By this, new project including the script can be created in the Spreadsheet as the container-bound script. If the Spreadsheet is not yours, you can create new project by sharing the Spreadsheet as a writer.

Comment: You should probably start using a more manageable script distribution model, i.e. an add-on or if you cannot manage that, a library with simple stubs in the client Sheets